# How To Center iFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment

I have a client who is using blogspot and I've tried everything I know to try and center the iframe which holds the link. However, i just can't seem to get it to work. Here is the code I am using, and suggestions?

```html
<section id="content">
  <div class="ic"></div>
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="newswrap">
        <iframe src="http://metiriusnews.blogspot.com/" width="100%" height="800px">
          <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
        </iframe>
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `width="100%"` — Since it starts at the very very left hand edge of its container and ends at the very very right hand ends of its container … how would centring it make a difference?

Comment: what is your problem? you set width 100%,

Comment: You will have to newswrap class to center as it is containing the iframe. 100% of ifrmae will be your newswrap  class width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a display block to your Iframe  and margin: 0 auto;

Or you can add to the Iframe  a display: inline-block and to .newswrap{text-align: center;} but be sure that wrapper and newswrap have width: 100%

Then your code should be:

```
.wrapper{width: 100%;} 
.newswrap{text-align: center;width: 100%;}
iframe{display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score -1):

iframe is inline element and you can do it via css adding `text-aling:center;` as in snippet below. But as you already have width:100% on Iframe, you probably have to align the container above the iframe using `margin:0 auto;` Also you structure has extra closing `</DIV>` which can be also an issue :

```css
.newswrap {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <div class="ic"></div>
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="newswrap">
        <iframe src="http://metiriusnews.blogspot.com/" width="100%" height="800px">
          <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this if you don't mind fixed width,also you can adjust the width

```
<style type="text/css">
iframe{
    width: 800px!important;
    margin:auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, nothing seems to work. Anything else I can try?

Comment: <section id="content">
  <div class="ic"></div>
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="newswrap">
      
        <iframe src="http://metiriusnews.blogspot.com/" width="600px" height="800px" class="newswrap">
          <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

^^ Current code